# MySQL Skip columns on condition

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following table:

> ```
> id   speed   date
> 1    0       01/01/2015     
> 2    0       01/01/2015 
> 3    0       01/01/2015 
> 4    0       01/01/2015 
> 5    0       01/01/2015 
> 6    0       01/01/2015 
> 7    25      01/01/2015 
> 8    78      01/01/2015 
> 9    13      01/01/2015 
> 10   45      01/01/2015 
> 11   0       01/01/2015 
> 12   80      01/01/2015 
> 13   86      01/01/2015 
> 14   10      01/01/2015 
> 15   0       01/01/2015 
> 16   0       01/01/2015 
> 17   0       01/01/2015 
> 18   0       01/01/2015
> ```

This is just a small part of the table, it has many dates. Each new date starts and ends with an unknown amount of zeros. And I have to skip these zeros and get only what's between them. So I came up with the following solution:

1. Get the ID of the first row whose speed is positive (in our table it's id number 4).
2. Get the ID of the last row whose speed is positive (in our table it's id number 12).
3. Get lines between these two IDs (4 and 12).

I get the `id` of the first row whose `speed` is positive:

```
$q1=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tableX WHERE speed > 0 order by date asc LIMIT 1");
$q1->execute();
$r1=$q1->fetch();
$first_id = $r1['id'];
```

And then get the `id` of the last row whose `speed` is positive:

```
$q2=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tableX WHERE speed > 0 order by date desc LIMIT 1");
$q2->execute();
$r2=$q2->fetch();
$last_id = $r2['id'];
```

And then use those `id`s to get what I want:

```
$q3=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tableX WHERE id between '$first_id' and '$last_id'");
$q3->execute();
while($r3=$q3->fetch(){}
```

Expected result:

> ```
> id   speed   date
> 7    25      01/01/2015 
> 8    78      01/01/2015 
> 9    13      01/01/2015 
> 10   45      01/01/2015 
> 11   0       01/01/2015 
> 12   80      01/01/2015 
> 13   86      01/01/2015 
> 14   10      01/01/2015
> ```

PS: row 11 is not a bug.

My code is actually working but I think this solution of mine is lame, so I am looking for an improvement, kind of all these three queries in one!

Comment: yes you can use single query for that. there is other solution

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: use variables if you want. It would be a single select statement with a cross join on a params derived table that jams variables into to query

Comment: Since this code is working and you are looking for an improvement, I'd suggest to ask on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want, but I think this will be equivalent to your whole code:

```
$q3=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tableX WHERE speed > 0");
$q3->execute();
while($r3=$q3->fetch(){}
```

Comment: Ok, I wrote this before your last edit I did not know what you want.
Even though you can improve your code and put all of your calls in one statement to reduce database call.

Comment: Here you go, i rephrased the question if that helps.

Comment: So you can try this one:
`SELECT * FROM tableX WHERE id 
between
 (SELECT id FROM tableX WHERE speed > 0 order by date desc LIMIT 1) and
 (SELECT id FROM tableX WHERE speed > 0 order by date asc LIMIT 1)` 
Not so advanced but combines all of your queries in one

Comment: I like that one but still not advanced as you said. But thanks anyway.